# Solving n simultaneous differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Is there a way to solve below  $n$ simultaneous differential equations in Mathematica?
$$i\frac{d}{dt}M_{n}\left(t\right)  =b\sqrt{N+3+n}M_{n+1}\left(t\right)+h\sqrt{n\left(2N+5\right)}M_{n-1}\left(t\right)
    $$
I also want to plot $M_{n}$.
h,b,N are constants.Range of n is from 0 to N

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: is the range of $n$ all of $\mathbb{Z}$? EDIT: ah I see. is $M_n$ for $n$ outside of that range identically 0, I'm guessing? also are there any initial conditions/functions?

Comment: Edited the question. As you said range is not a matter here. Also no initial conditions

Comment: So, you want to find the general symbolic solution for the system? Is $N$ a known number, or you want a solution involving $N$ as a parameter?

Comment: @xzczd Actually I need the general symbolic solution for the system. Also need a plot for M_n for different times

Comment: `I need the general symbolic solution for the system`  You can't plot a general symbolic solution without giving specific values for all unknowns and also initial conditions. You also have one remaining unknown function on the RHS, $M_{n+1}(t)$ when $n=N$ which has no ODE. You need to give a definition for this. The first one $M_{n-1}(t)$ when $n=0$ is not needed since it is multiplied by zero and goes away.

Comment: @Nasser For getting the M_0 and M_2 we can consider the simplest case of N=2 and solve by means of the eigenvalue- eigenvector method. I also don't know how to implement that in Mathematica.

Comment: You've essentially changed the question to another one, please avoid this. Consider posting a new question.

Comment: @xzczd new question posted

Comment: @xzczd I reverted it back. But my first question itself is not completely answered yet. How do we know the M_n+1 prior each time? That's what I asked for any way through coding

Comment: I have heard of some ghost functions in Matlab to do that. Is there any such functions in Mathematica

Comment: So, you're expecting the eigenvalue-eigenvector method to handle the unknown $M_{N+1}$? If so,  then you're in the wrong direction. The $M_{N+1}$ should be supplemented by you, it's not something can be resolved by turning to another method or software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For small number of ODE's, Mathematica `DSolve` solves it, but it takes longer time as more ODE's are added.

```
ClearAll[t, h, b, r, n];
NN = 2;
odes = Table[
  I ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]]'[t] == 
   b Sqrt[NN + 3 + n]*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n + 1]][t] + 
    h *Sqrt[n*(2*NN + 5)]*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n - 1]][t], 
    {n, 0, NN}
];
deps = Table[ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]][t], {n, 0, NN}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now call `DSolve`

```
 DSolve[odes, deps, t]
```

The solution is too long to post. For `N=6` you get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now it will take much longer time to solve it. I did not want to wait for it.

You did not say how big `N` is. (btw, `N` is reserved, so better use different letter)

**Edit**

To answers comments. To hope to get a solution that can be plotted, need to supply IC and values for the missing parameters $h,b$ and the last $M(t)$. Here is an example for 3 equations just for illustration.

```
ClearAll[t, h, b, n, M];
NN = 2;
h = 5; b = 6; (*some made up values*)
odes = Table[
  I ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]]'[t] == 
   b Sqrt[NN + 3 + n]*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n + 1]][t] + 
    h *Sqrt[n*(2*NN + 5)]*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n - 1]][t], {n,
    0, NN}] 
deps = Table[ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]][t], {n, 0, NN}] 
M3[t_] := 2*t; (*some function for the last one, which has no ODE*)
ic = {M0[0] == 1, M1[1] == 2, M2[0] == 2}; (*some IC*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now solve the system

```
DSolve[{odes, ic}, deps, t]
```

Now the solutions can be plotted. But they are complex. So can plot either the abs or imaginary or real parts. They are complex, since your ODE is complex.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For example

```
 Plot[Re[M0[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Re[M1[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc.

Btw, if IC and other values are available, it will be better to use `NDSolve` instead of `DSolve` for this. `DSolve` takes too long time for large `N`.

Comment: I want to get a plot as well.

Comment: The solution I got when used your code, has un-evaluated integrals.

Comment: @Jasmine it is not possible to get a plot, since there are many unknowns in the solution. To obtain a plot, you need to specify values for `h,b` and initial conditions, and also definition for the last $M__{N+1}(t)$ function. Since that remains undefined. Once you do all this, then DSolve was able to give exact solutions that can be plotted. (But they are complex, since your input is complex).  Btw, why did you edit your question and removed `Range of n is from 0 to N` from it?  My solution was based on that.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 `DSolve` gives an integral, since it does not know what one unknown function $M__{N+1}(t)$ is. This needs to be supplied by the user, then it will integrate it.

Comment: @Nasser yes, yes. No argument here. I just mentioned it for completeness.

Comment: @Nasser The idea is that we will get M_0  and M_2 by considering the simplest case of N=2 and solve by means of the eigen value- eigenvector method. I thought you might be solving by that way! Is there any such possibility

Comment: @Nasser  I use NDSolve[{odes, ic}, deps, {t, 0, 50}] // FullSimplify But I can't plot! Can you mention how to plot using NDSolve?

Comment: @Jasmine have you checked what the documentation on `NDSolve` indicates for plotting your result? If so, where do you find your confusion? If not, it is helpful to check there for their examples of how to plot your result.

Comment: I got clarified on NDSolve. But NDSolve is also too slow.