# Too slow using Dsolve

Tags: differential-equations, simulation

I am referring to the accepted answer to the question: [Solving n simultaneous differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246199/solving-n-simultaneous-differential-equation)
The issue is that the code is running too slow for even N=5! Is there any way to make it faster?
I tried NDSolve as well. It’s also too slow!
I am using the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ClearAll[t, h, b, n, M];
NN = 5;
h = 21; b = 400;(*some made up values*)odes = 
 Table[I ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]]'[t] == 
   b Sqrt[NN + 3 + n]*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n + 1]][t] + 
    h*Sqrt[n*(2*NN + 5)]*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n - 1]][t], {n, 
   0, NN}]
deps = Table[ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]][t], {n, 0, NN}]
M6[t_] := 2;(*some function for the last one,which has no ODE*)ic = \
{M0[0] == 1, M1[1] == 2, M2[0] == 3, M3[0] == 2, M4[0] == 1, 
  M5[0] == 4};(*some IC*)
NDSolve[{odes, ic}, deps, {t, 0, 3000}]
lot[{Evaluate[(M0[t]*Conjugate[M0[t]])] /. MH, 
  Evaluate[(M1[t]*Conjugate[M1[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M2[t]*Conjugate[M2[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M3[t]*Conjugate[M3[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M4[t]*Conjugate[M4[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M5[t]*Conjugate[M5[t]]) /. MH]}, {t, 0, 3000}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: `I tried NDSolve as well. It’s also too slow!` then you should post the code you tried. For me `NDSolve` finishes instantly for `N=5` and for `N=10`

Comment: @Nasser Please see the edited question with code.

Comment: It only took 136 seconds for NDSolve to complete on my computer using V 12.2 and 12.3. This is not too slow considering your `t` goes up to `3000` now.   Try `Timing@NDSolve[{odes, ic}, deps, {t, 0, 3000}]` and see what you get for the time used. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz8MM.png)

Comment: @Nasser Also I am not getting any result for larger t value

Comment: Jasmine, what do you mean by `not getting any result`? Can you, please, be more specific about what you expected to occur, and what it was that actually did occur?

Comment: In `ic` is it supposed to be `M1[1] == 2` or `M1[0] == 2` -- that is, is the problem supposed to be a BVP or an IVP?  (In the current set up, it uses the shooting method to solve the BVP, which means it is solving many IVPs searching for the solution. That's why it's so slow, I think.)

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

Try

```
sols = Solve[odes, D[deps, t]][[1]]
A = Grad[(D[deps, t] /. sols), deps]
MatrixExp[A t]
```

or also use

```
{Lambda,T} = Eigensystem[A]
```

then calling

```
udeps = Table[u[k][t],{k,1,6}];
```

we solve

```
deps = Inverse[T].udeps/.DSolve[Thread[D[udeps, t] == Lambda.udeps],udeps, t]
```

following with the initial conditions.