# Solving simultaneous differential equations using eigen value method

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I wish to solve the following set of ODE.
$$i\frac{d}{dt}B_{n}\left(t\right)  =f\sqrt{\left(P-n\right)\left(n+1\right)}B_{n+1}\left(t\right)+f\sqrt{n\left(P-n+1\right)}B_{n-1}\left(t\right)
+   Y\left[\left(P-n\right)\left(P-n-1\right)+n\left(n-1\right)\right]B_{n}\left(t\right)$$
The question is similar to the [Solving n simultaneous differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246199/solving-n-simultaneous-differential-equation?noredirect=1#comment619905_246199).It's working perfectly for N=2 case. But the method is not giving any results for larger N with larger time say t=0 to 3000, and varying constants.

Values of constants are $f=20$ , $Y=334$. Also $n=0,1,2,...P$

When we consider a simple case, $P=2$ we get 3 simulatneous ODE as follows.
$$\frac{d}{dt}B_{0}\left(t\right)   =-iYB_{0}\left(t\right)-i\sqrt{2}fB_{1}\left(t\right)$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}B_{1}\left(t\right)   =-i\sqrt{2}fB_{0}\left(t\right)-i\sqrt{2}fB_{2}\left(t\right)$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}B_{2}\left(t\right)   =-i\sqrt{2}fB_{1}\left(t\right)-iYB_{2}\left(t\right)$$

The idea is to solve the above equation by finding eigen values and eigen vectors. We can convert the above equation in a matrix form as follows:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{d}{dt}B_{0}\left(t\right)\\
\frac{d}{dt}B_{1}\left(t\right)\\
\frac{d}{dt}B_{2}\left(t\right)
\end{pmatrix}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-iY & -i\sqrt{2}f & 0\\
-i\sqrt{2}f & 0 & -i\sqrt{2}f\\
0 & -i\sqrt{2}f & -iY
\end{array}\right)\begin{pmatrix}B_{0}\left(t\right)\\
B_{1}\left(t\right)\\
B_{2}\left(t\right)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let $$S=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-iY & -i\sqrt{2}f & 0\\
-i\sqrt{2}f & 0 & -i\sqrt{2}f\\
0 & -i\sqrt{2}f & -iY
\end{array}\right)$$

For solving the set of differential equations we need to find the eigen values and eigenvectors of $S$. When we calcualte them, it turns out to be 3 complex and distinct eigen values and 3 eigenvectors corresponding to each eigenvalues. Thus the solution will be:

$$B_{n}\left(t\right)=\sum_{n}G_{n}\overline{j}e^{\lambda t}$$

provided: $\overline{j}$ are eigen vectors and $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

$G_{n}$ can be solved using the initial condition, $$B_{n}\left(0\right)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

The above is just $P=2$ case. Any way to extend the above for $n$ case?

After that I need to plot the modulus square of the coeficcients with respect to time in a single plot.

What I have tried using NDSolve is:

```
 NN = 5;

f = 20



Y = 334



 N1 = Sqrt[(NN - n)*(n + 1)];

N2 = Sqrt[n*(NN - n + 1)];
 N3 = ((NN - n)*(NN - n - 1)) + (n*(n - 1));

FT = f*N1



ST = f*N2



TT = (Y/2)*N3


 odes = Table[
   I ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]]'[t] == 
    FT*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n + 1]][t] + 
     ST*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n - 1]][t] + 
     TT*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]][t], {n, 0, NN}];

deps = Table[ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]][t], {n, 0, NN}]

 {M0[t], M1[t], M2[t], M3[t], M4[t], M5[t]}

 ic = {M0[0] == 1, M1[0] == 0, M2[0] == 0, M3[0] == 0, M4[0] == 0, M5[0] == 0}


MH = NDSolve[{odes, ic}, deps, {t, 0, 3000}] 
  


Plot[{Evaluate[(M0[t]*Conjugate[M0[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M1[t]*Conjugate[M1[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M2[t]*Conjugate[M2[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M3[t]*Conjugate[M3[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M4[t]*Conjugate[M4[t]]) /. MH], 
  Evaluate[(M5[t]*Conjugate[M5[t]]) /. MH]}, {t, 0, 3000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I don't see what the issue is to be honest. Have you tried the obvious? Eigenvalues[Smatrix] and Eigenvectors[Smatrix] with Smatrix being the matrix you wrote down?

Comment: I have tried and right now I am getting results for N=2. But not for large N. Of course they are the values of S matrix

Comment: So, to rephrase: is the real question how to write a command to generate the S-matrix for general values of N?

Comment: Nop. I want to solve simultaneous ODE using the method I described above

Comment: Hence you need to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the S-matrix for different values of N. No?

Comment: Jasmine, can you, please, include the code you have tried so far, or what exists in other related questions that you are having trouble with? It is hard to help debug and solve such problems otherwise.

Comment: As I described in the question, as a first step I need to write down the N differential equations. Eg: if N=20, I need 20 simultaneous differential equations. After that I need to write S matrix using that. Then have to find out it’s eigen values and eigen vectors. Then solutions

Comment: @CATrevillian Please see the code I have tried

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you have very fast oscillating solutions besides very slow varying ones.

I calculated (with some simplifications) in reasonable time the solution for NN=4 and tmax=1000:

```
NN = 4;
tmax = 1000;
f = 20;
Y = 334;
N1 = Sqrt[(NN - n)*(n + 1)];
N2 = Sqrt[n*(NN - n + 1)];
N3 = ((NN - n)*(NN - n - 1)) + (n*(n - 1));
FT = f*N1;
ST = f*N2;
TT = (Y/2)*N3;

odes = Table[
   I ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]]'[t] == 
    FT*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n + 1]][t] + 
     ST*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n - 1]][t] + 
     TT*ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]][t], {n, 0, NN}];

deps = Table[ToExpression["M" <> ToString[n]][t], {n, 0, NN}];
ic = Prepend[Thread[Rest[deps /. t -> 0] == 0], M0[0] == 1];

(MH = NDSolve[Flatten@{odes, ic}, deps, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]] ;
  
  Plot[#, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     PlotRange -> All] & /@ ((deps Conjugate[deps]) /. MH)
  ) // Timing
```

[image]

As you can see, it took 138 sec and the main point is, that solutions 2,3,4 oscillate very fast. How really fast you can see, if we plot solution 2 for 1/1000 of tmax, time t=0 to t=1:

```
Plot[Evaluate[(deps Conjugate[deps]) /. MH[[2]]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This should illuminate the problem enough.

What can be done? Do you need the accurate solutions of the fast varying parts? If yes, you could calculate the fast changing parts over a small time interval and replace the slow moving parts by constants. On the other hand, the slow moving parts seem to feel only an average of the fast parts, so you could replace the fast parts in the equations for the slow parts by an average.

Comment: This is awesome and the behavior is expected. But in the question, I have mentioned NN=5 and tmax=3000 It's taking very long time! Any way to reduce time

Comment: It is no surprise that it takes very long if you calculate nearly a million of periods of periods. But is this really necessary? What do you want to do with it?  Some background is needed.

Comment: I found a paper in the arXiv and trying to replicate the Fig1 in the paper, <https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04900> They are using a different time scale!

Comment: Is there a possibility to rescale x axis in such a way to get a plot with new time, $$t=(\pi/4)*t’/Tn$$ : Here  t’ is the old time from 0 to 1000, Tn is a particular time in which the value of B_0(t’)*conjugate[B_0(t’)]  and B_N(t’)*conjugate[B_N(t’)] nearly equal to .5

Comment: Do you want only to draw the  known solution y[t'] with a new time scale t ? For this you would  plot: f[4 Tn t / Pi]  If you want equations in t you have to replace multiply t' and dt' by a factor of: 4 Tn / Pi

Comment: How can I find Tn via programme? That is how to select the time at which B_0(t’)*conjugate(B_0(t’)) and B_NN(t’)*conjugate(B_NN(t’) nearly equal to .5

Comment: Read about "WhenEvent" in the help.

Comment: When I use the command NDSolve[Flatten@{odes, ic, 
     WhenEvent[M0[t]*Conjugate[M0[t]] == .5, Print[t]]}, 
   deps, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]; I am getting the answer for all times. I need only the answer for maximum time.

Comment: For example if I am rescaling as; tn=8;tbar=tn/t;(MH = NDSolve[Flatten@{odes, ic}, deps, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
  Plot[#, {t, 0, tbar}, 
     PlotRange -> All] & /@ ((deps Conjugate[deps]) /. MH)) // Timing         The above code is not rescaling the answer!

Comment: @ Daniel Huber Also I want all plots in a single plot.

Comment: Use `WhenEvent[M0[t]*Conjugate[M0[t]] == .5, tend=t; "StopIntegration"]`

Comment: It's not working. This is because it's changing the shape of the plot!